# Does Unison socket mode support ipv6

Tags: windows, backup, sync, unison

I have been using Unison for quite some time now for synchronizing data between my machines, and I am very happy with it. Now I need to synchronize two new machines connected via ipv6, but they won't connect. One of the machines is running `unison -socket 1234` and the other one is connecting to socket://fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx%11:1234/D:/Dir1. If I switch to ipv4 (and of course changing the server name accordingly in the connection string), I am able to connect.

Does anyone know if Unison even supports ipv6 in socket mode? If so, is there a way to bind to an ipv6 address?

If you were wondering why I cannot use ipv4, the answer is that i am connected through VPN on one of the machines. Since the VPN client does not allow split tunneling, I cannot reach the machine through ipv4.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the address in []s: `socket://[fe80::...%11]:1234/D:/` This is normally required for IPv6 addresses in URLs.

Comment: Tried that, but that gave me a `Fatal error - ill-formed root specification socket`